# Copy multiple files from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am having trouble downloading multiple files from AWS S3 buckets to my local machine.

I have all the filenames that I want to download and I do not want others. How can I do that ? Is there any kind of loop in aws-cli I can do some iteration ?

There are couple hundreds files I need to download so that it seems not possible to use one single command that takes all filenames as arguments.

Comment: you can look at `aws s3api get-object` if you're able to filter/query the list of your files .. if you have the list in a file, you can read the file by line and pipe with `aws s3 cp s3://yourbuyet/-`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to include and copy files that are in current directory to s3 (and not recursively)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711300/how-to-include-and-copy-files-that-are-in-current-directory-to-s3-and-not-recur)

Comment: @FredericHenri could you elaborate on how to read a file in this case?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a bash script which can read all the filenames from a file `filename.txt`.

```
#!/bin/bash  
set -e  
while read line  
do  
  aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/$line dest-path/  
done <filename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely better way to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is much better way to do it compared to all other answers posted here.
Thank you for sharing this answer.

Comment: `set -e stops the execution of a script if a command or pipeline has an error - which is the opposite of the default shell behaviour, which is to ignore errors in scripts`

Comment: This will download files one after the other - need a way to do it in parallel

Comment: its too slow,may be its taking time locating those files.is there anyway by which I can send multiple file request at the same time and those files located and download in parallel ?

Comment: Yea, this is too slow. What I really want is to use the --include flag, but match a list of a million files.

Answer (score 81):

Also one can use the `--recursive` option, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) for `cp` command. It will copy all objects under a specified prefix recursively.

Example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://folder1/folder2/folder3 . --recursive
```

will grab all files under folder1/folder2/folder3 and copy them to local directory.

Comment: Powerful, but an (obvious?) warning to use with care. AWS charges for every in/out file transfer. And when combined with the `rm` command, check your syntax to avoid accidental deletion!

Comment: Is there any specific order on how the files will be copied? As in files having an ending number (file_1, file_2, ...) will they be copied in order and nothing can be said about it?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which wants to only copy specific files, by name/filepath.

Answer (score 39):

You might want to use "sync" instead of "cp". The following will download/sync only the files with the ".txt" extension in your local folder:

```
aws s3 sync --exclude="*" --include="*.txt" s3://mybucket/mysubbucket .
```

Comment: I would like to use the above command to copy just 100 files (for example).
Is there a clever way/parameter that can be used to do this?

Answer (score 31):

As per the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) you can use `include` and `exclude` filters with `s3 cp` as well. So you can do something like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/ . --recursive --exclude="*" --include="2017-12-20*"
```

Make sure you get the order of `exclude` and `include` filters right as that could change the whole meaning.

Comment: Your last line _"Make sure you get the order of exclude and include filters right as that could change the whole meaning."_ is especially helpful (I had them reversed). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Tried all the above. Not much joy. Finally, adapted @rajan's reply into a one-liner:

```
for file in whatever*.txt; do { aws s3 cp $file s3://somewhere/in/my/bucket/; } done
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to read s3 object keys from a text file and download them to my machine parallelly.

I used this command

```
cat <filename>.txt | parallel aws s3 cp {} <output_dir>
```

The contents of my text file looked like this:

```
s3://bucket-name/file1.wav
s3://bucket-name/file2.wav
s3://bucket-name/file3.wav
```

Please make sure you don't have an empty line at the end of your text file. You can learn more about GNU parallel [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Answer (score 1):

@Rajan's answer is a very good one, however it fails when there is no match found in the **.txt* file and the source s3 bucket, however below code resolves also this issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
aws s3 cp s3://your-s3-source-bucket/folder/$line s3://your-s3-destination/folder/
done <try.txt
```

The only thing you need is to run the bash file inside you aws notebook.

```
!chmod +x YOUR-BASH-NAME.sh
!./YOUR-BASH-NAME.sh
```

Answer (score -4):

I got the problem solved, may be a little bit stupid, but it works.

Using python, I write multiple line of AWS download commands on one single .sh file, then I execute it on the terminal.

Comment: you have plenty of ready to use sdk's [here](http://aws.amazon.com/code) in the amazon website.